# How to update JSPM dependency for local component

Tags: jspm

I am developing component which is JSPM dependency for master application.
I linked this component using `jspm link` and `jspm install --link component` for app. Everything works until i change dependencies in child component.
I tried `jspm update component` but it does nothing - main app still has error because dependency was not installed for master app and master app's config.js -> map was not updated with component dependencies.

Q: How to make JSPM update single component developed locally

More general question - is there easy way to develop local JSPM components and update master applications because now it is really painfull.

Answer (score -3):

I just found and tested perfect solution for above JSPM problem and also for JSPM problem with accessing SASS files in dependencies and Typescript problem with finding modules in JSPM folder structure:

`npm uninstall jspm`

`npm install webpack --save-dev`

And I am happy :-)